# Why BGP implements its own keepalive instead of using tcp keepalive?

Tags: bgp, tcp

BGP doesn't use TCP keepalive, it uses its own keepalive mechanism. My question is why can't bgp turn-on the SO_KEEPaLIVE of TCP and live happily? why does it not use tcp keepalive and implement its own keepalive ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TCP "keepalive" is a feature that is not present on all operating systems. It is not in the TCP standard itself and it's not reliable. [RC1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) specifes it, but explicitly states:

> Implementors MAY include "keep-alives" in their TCP
> implementations, although this practice is not universally
> accepted.  If keep-alives are included, the application MUST
> be able to turn them on or off for each TCP connection, and
> they MUST default to off.

Even more important:

> It is extremely important to remember that ACK segments that
> contain no data are not reliably transmitted by TCP.
> Consequently, if a keep-alive mechanism is implemented it
> MUST NOT interpret failure to respond to any specific probe
> as a dead connection.

TCP keepalive uses the TCP protocol in a special way, sending a duplicate ACK with no data attached to it. Thing is: You can't count on it being available. Also some firewalls filter TCP keepalives.

For BGP to function correctly you need a way to implement specific timers for keepalive (how often do we send a message) and hold (after which time do we declare a peer to be non-responsive) that are **reliably** sent. So BGP is using it's own keepalive message which is not a lot of overhead (19 bytes) compared to TCP keepalive.